# How to Get rid of "File is read-only" in android studio?

Tags: android, apk

[image]I downloaded the android source code from [this F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.ligi.survivalmanual). When I tried to edit the file in android studio i am getting pop-up message 
which tells "**File is Read-only**", which doesn't allow me to edit any of the codes.

I tackled with other problems before but I stuck with this. Am I downloading the source code in the wrong way? I just downloaded the **apk** file and opened it in android studio. I saw the PGP signature but I don't know what to do with it since I am new to android studio. Is there any other options which I can disable to make this go? I already tried switching the "**Mark File Read-only**" in File but it doesn't work.
Please somebody help me with this.

Comment: What file you are trying to edit? Share the screen shot where you are getting "File is Read-only".

Comment: An APK file is not source code. It is an application bundle that you can install on an Android device. There is a link on the page to download the source code from github.

Comment: @VaradMondkar i added the screenshot above!

Comment: @JimRhodes I already Tried to use this [github](https://github.com/ligi/SurvivalManual), even though i am able to edit the codes in that github, i didn't get all the features of the orginal app! All i can see is just a layout and basic information when i run that github code! i didn't get the main content of the app! by using the apk i got everthing perfect but i am unable to edit that!

Comment: is this file editable in notepad (for example)